# css add two div with absolute position in container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work with bootstrap 3 and need to add two shadows into container. the first top of the container and next bottom of the container with absolute position.

CSS:

```
.section-st1 {
    padding: 0px;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.section-st1 .shadowtop {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-1px;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
.section-st1 .shadowbot {
    margin-bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
```

HTML :

```
<section class="section section-st1 section-align-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="shadowtop">
            <img alt="shadow1" src="img/shadow-top.png"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <h2>welcome to</h2>

                <p>Vestibulum nunc erat, venenatis tristique nisi sit amet, volutpat accumsan lorem. Sed quis tortor magna. Maecenas hendrerit feugiat pulvinar. Aenean condimentum quam eu ultricies cursus. Nulla facilisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut nec tellus neque. Sed non dui eget arcu elementum facilisis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shadowbot">
            <img alt="shadow2" src="img/shadow-bot.png"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I add `position: absolute` for the first shadow and this worked true But the next shadow does not show in the container. How do fix this problem?

DEMO:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.section-st1 {
  padding: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.section-st1 .shadowtop {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.section-st1 .shadowbot {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section class="section section-st1 section-align-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="shadowtop">
      <img alt="shadow1" src="https://loremflickr.com/500/3?random=1" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>welcome to</h2>
        <p>Vestibulum nunc erat, venenatis tristique nisi sit amet, volutpat accumsan lorem. Sed quis tortor magna. Maecenas hendrerit feugiat pulvinar. Aenean condimentum quam eu ultricies cursus. Nulla facilisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut nec
          tellus neque. Sed non dui eget arcu elementum facilisis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadowbot">
      <img alt="shadow2" src="https://loremflickr.com/500/3?random=2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think that settings `position:relative;` to bottom shadow will work.

Comment: @Banzay: Sure, But in need to `position:absolute` for show content over of shadow div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7eHFd/76/)

make container relative and set bottom in negative

```
body {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.container{ position:relative;}
.section-st1 {
    padding: 0px;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.section-st1 .shadowtop {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-1px;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
.section-st1 .shadowbot {
    bottom:-3px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control position of shadow to the parent block with css properties: top, right,bottom, left;
In your case, for bottom block set bottom:0;

And remember If you use position:absolute, set position: relative for parent block;

```
body{margin-top:10px;}
.section-st1 {
    padding: 0px;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.section-st1 .shadowtop {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-1px;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
.section-st1 .shadowbot {
    margin-bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `bottom:0` instead of `margin-bottom`

```
.section-st1 .shadowbot 
 {
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#e1e1e1;
 }
```

Comment: This not Work. if set `bottom:0` shadow show in bottom of page(outer container) http://jsfiddle.net/7eHFd/73/